# If SqlDataReader is going to be disposed, do I need to call close()?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

If I instantiate a SqlDataReader inside a `using` block, do I need to call `close()` on the reader?

Simple example of looking up a user shown below.

```
  using (var connection = new SqlConnection(Settings.GetValue("SqlConnection")))
  {
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * from Users where Id = @Id", connection);        
    command.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier);
    command.Parameters["@Id"].Value = id;

    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReaderWithRetry())
    {
      reader.Read();

      if (reader.HasRows)
      {
        //Do work
      }

      //Is this neccesary?
      reader.Close();
    }
  }
```

Comment: You'll find answers to similar topis on SO.

Comment: Side note: `SqlCommand` also implements `IDisposable`.

Comment: @JeffO Dang it, I thought SO would tell me this question doesn't belong.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If it's in a using block, then it is automatically closed.  You do not need to explicitly close it.

BTW the SqlCommand in your example is disposable.  You should create it in a using block too, otherwise any resources it controls won't be let go until the garbage collector collects.

Your undisposed SqlCommand is actually a good example of why C#'s emulation of RAII is not "real" RAII. You must take an explicit action (making blocks) for the RAII to kick in which is equivalent to an explicit close albeit with different syntax.

Comment: You could also look at it differently: if you don't use `using`, it's as if you used `new` in C++.